# How to detect whether a class has no virtual base in C++17 at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++17, compile-time

Given:

1. A type T that is defined;
2. Any tools you want.

How to detect whether T has no virtual bases in C++17 at compile time?

Edit:

I'm actually writing a type-erased container, and when I was writing the code for getting the copy ctor, I found that as long as a class has no
 virtual base and has no user-provided copy ctor, copy ctor can then be a pointer to stuff like std::memcpy.

Comment: Doesn't seem  possible.

Comment: Yeah I agree. If your program needs to know this specifically there's probably a design flaw of some kind.

Comment: This is where we ask what do you want to do that requires this? This sounds like a XY problem

Comment: Is `std::is_trivially_copyable<T>` what you really need? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable

Comment: This will returns false if the class has vtable. In my case, I don't mind whether vtable is present.

Comment: Assuming the object is meant to be copied in the first place (there are plenty of examples of things that shouldn't be copied - file handles, pointers, locks, and many others), then if it doesn't have a copy-ctor, it should always be safe to copy it with std::memcpy. I don't understand why having virtual base would affect that.

Comment: I'm writing type-erasure container, sth. like std::function, that's why I need to get a pointer to copy ctor.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Oh, handles and pointers should be copied. It's just a problem if those specific instances *own* their resource...

Comment: I assuming using [`std::is_polymorphic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic) would also help answer this question.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu you should care whether a vtable is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *might* be able to determine this based on the size of a pointer to a member function of the class, if you are using **Microsoft Visual C++**.  It does not work with other compilers, particularly ones implementing the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#member-pointers).

With the Microsoft implementation, the layout of a class can vary depending on the location of the virtual base class, and a pointer-to-member-function will need an offset applied to get the correct `this` pointer for the call.  This can cause a pointer-to-member-function to be larger when a virtual base class is present than it is when there is not a virtual base.  Since the `sizeof` operator is a compile time constant, this can be used in various places (including template parameters) to differentiate the code based on the presence of a virtual base.

Here's a simple test program (and on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/kiuYdL)).  If it compiles you can use the size of a member function pointer to determine if a virtual base class is specified for a class.

```
struct B {
    void f();
};

struct C: virtual public B {
    void g();
};

int test(int s) {
    switch (s) {
        case sizeof(&C::g):
            return 1;
        case sizeof(&B::f):
            return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @n.m. I did emphasize _might_ in the first sentence.

Comment: This method won't work as long as the compiler use Itanium abi. For most of the compiler on linux, they use this abi and this is shall to fail. @1201ProgramAlarm check this: https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#member-pointers.

Comment: Well, it works in MSVC in their default non-conforming mode. Are there any others?

Answer (score 3):

For to find out if you can use `std::memcpy`, you actually need `std::is_trivially_meowable`.

For example, If you want to copy using `std::memcpy`, you can check this with [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable).

You can also check for trivially constructible and trivially destructible.

---

As you said in the comment, you also want to do this with non trivial classes. This inevitably lead to undefined behavior, so I wouldn't try it. I'd suggest removing the vtable in those classes and making them trivial before relying on underfined behavior.

Also, if you use pointers to those classes, the pointer themselves are trivial. So you can copy your class trivially that way.

Comment: heh, *"meowable"*

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I spent too much time with STL